# CI/CD WPF setup file using Azure Pipelines

Tags: wpf, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have successfully created a Repo on Azure Devops and a Pipeline which triggers a release every time I push to the master branch. The result of the release is an .exe file that I can download from the Artifacts explorer. If I download the release and open it, the WPF app simply runs (no install required). I'm trying to wrap my head around how this whole CI/CD process would work but I just cannot find any good examples that could help me understand the deployment process(at least for WPF apps).

What I would usually do is build a WPF App, once I'm done, I add a new project to the solution (Visual Studio Installer - Setup Project) and deliver the .msi installer to the end user (for updates I send them the latest version to install).

How can I make this process a lot more smoother using CI/CD in Azure Devops? How do I generate an actual installer? Do I use some logic in the app itself to check for the latest build in Azure? Can someone please lay out some simple steps or some good resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a task like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.BuildInstaller to use the VS Installer project you have traditionally used.

This task wraps the calls to devenv that are needed to drive VS Installer to create its MSI package as it doesn't use the usual MSBuild engine to do this.

Other tools do a similar job, for example you could drive WIX or a similar tool to create the MSI package however if you are familiar with VS Installer Projects you may want to stick to this.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. It's a step in the right direction but I am struggling to get it to work. Do I need to configure my on build agent(on premise)? I tried it that way and I get this error: `2018-11-27T17:41:13.0687513Z DEBUG: Aggregated: System.Object[]\devenv.com
2018-11-27T17:41:13.4277529Z ##[error]Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: System.Object[].` If I try it with the Hosted2017 Agent Pool, this is the result: 
`##[error]Cannot find path 'D:\a\1\s\Setup\release\' because it does not exist.`

Comment: Did the build create the MSI OK? i.e. does the task report success? I can't work out from this snippet what stage is failing.

Comment: Building the solution is successful but Creating .msi file from VS Installer project fails with the above message. I tried putting the step before or after the publishing of the Artifact step and still cannot get it to work. Thank you for your support.

Comment: So this is the output from the VS Build Installer task that is failing? What inputs did you give to the task?

Comment: Yes. that is right. Please see below:
`- task: dutchworkz.BuildInstaller.BuildInstaller.BuildInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Create .msi file(s) from VS Installer project(s).'
  inputs:
    installTaskMode: vdproj

    SlnPath: 'MyProject.sln'

    VdprojPath: MySetupProject/MySetupProject.vdproj`